# function in R that creates a new column in a data.table, whose i-th row is the sum of product of two columns starting from i+1 row

Tags: r, data.table

Example:

```
data.table(x=1:3, y=4:6)
```

I want to insert a new column whose values would be:

```
z=(2*5+3*6, 3*6, NA)
```

I tried to create this function firstly but it doesnt work :

```
sumprod <- function(x, y){
  z=vector()
  for (i in 1:length(x)-1){
    z=c(z, sum(shift(x, n=i+1, type="lag")*shift(y, n=i+1, type="lag"), na.rm=FALSE))
  }
  return(z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, z := rev(cumsum(rev(Reduce(`*`, shift(.SD, type = "lead",
    fill = 0)))))]
dt1[z == 0, z := NA_real_]
```

-output

```
> dt1
   x y  z
1: 1 4 28
2: 2 5 18
3: 3 6 NA
```

---

Or with `fcumsum`

```
library(collapse)
dt1[, z := fcumsum(shift(do.call(`*`, .SD), type = "lead")[.N:1])[.N:1]]
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- data.table(x=1:3, y=4:6)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, one more question : .SD does it for the whole data.table, how can I select to do it only for 2 columns of the data.table

Comment: @Tessa You can specify `.SDcols = c("x", "y")`

Answer (score 0):

You could `Reduce` using `right=T` argument (from right to left):

```
dt[,z:=shift(Reduce('+',x*y,accumulate=T,right=T),-1)][]

       x     y     z
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     1     4    28
2:     2     5    18
3:     3     6    NA
```